# git workflow with multiple, different remotes

Tags: git, workflow, githooks

At work, we developed scripts and extensions to Nagios. We provide a supervision service to ~30 customers (each customer having a Nagios server). Some customers have specific configuration (new modules to check something very specific, yet to be included in mainline... or not).

Right now, the Nagios servers versions differs a lot (some servers are 2 years old, and no updates planned).

I'm wondering about switching to git to automate deployments, and using continuous integration to be sure we don't break something on a client's Nagios.

Here is my idea :

```
                        1 single server
                                    \___________________________________________________
                                     |                                                 |
 dev1 -----\               /---------|---> remote1 (bare) ----> remote1 (nagios etc/)  |
            \             /          |_________________________________________________|
             \           /
              \         /
 dev2 ---- main server (bare) -----------> remote2 (bare) ----> remote2 (nagios etc/)

 ...
```

The devs, and main server are located at the office, when the bare remotes + remotes are located at the customers'.

I've already managed to automagically push to remotes using the post receive hook.

From remote1 (bare) to remote1, I could use another hook that would cd to remote1, and git pull. Then I could test the configuration via a simple Nagios command, and revert to previous commit in case something goes wrong.

About the files are are different between remotes, I could just gitignore them for the moment or use different branches on the main server (so I can push customer1 branch to remote1).

What do you think about it ? I'm open to any advice, or suggestion :-)

The bare + non bare repositories seems a little bit weird, and also I'm unsure about the roll back if some commit doesn't work as expected.

Comment: +1 for pretty ascii graph. that's almost forgotten skill/art.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is possible to use git as a deployment tool, that's not really its intended function.  Perhaps you should consider [cfengine](http://cfengine.com/) or [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So you believe I should split development and deployment? I already know a little of puppet, I'll also take a look at cfengine.

Comment: I have no doubt it's possible to set up a deployment system involving multiple hosts using git hooks, and it sounds like you've already started down that path; maybe that meets your needs.  It is true though that git was designed with revision tracking in mind, not deployment, even if it has evolved to the point where it's useful for both.